# Access to __MDrivenServer locked

Tags: mdriven

Although I have been using ECO from a few years, I am very new to MDriven Turnkey.

I have created an account and a site in portal.mdriven.net, but when I visit MDrivenServer I get the following message:

You currently do not have access - this is due to setting AdminRequireIdentification==true and you do not have correct role

According to the help manual in MDrivenTheBook Part 10 MDrivenTurnkey:
"When you have accidently locked yourself out you can find the admin database, open it with SqlServerCompact tools. Find table admin_GlobalSettings and set column TurnOffRegistration to 0 (false) – now you may register a new user and regain control."
The database is located in __MDrivenServer\App_Data\DatabaseCompact.sdf

I have Visual Studio 2010 and I have also downloaded the SQL Server Compact Tools, but I have not idea how to open the 
https://SchoolAurelio.azurewebsites.net/__MDrivenServer/App_Data/DatabaseCompact.sdf in order to set the column TurnOffRegistration to 0.

How can I update the sdf file?

Thanks,

Jose Maria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Compact tools you do something like "connect" and choose the sdf downloaded file. Once there there you can do sql on the ASP_User table.

BUT - in the portal.mdriven.net you have a SendSettingsAndRestart, this operation should unlock a locked mdriven-database. It will also inject a new pwd if you have changed it in portal. Please try this operation and see if things clear up.

Comment: You are right. After SendSettingsAndRestart I can access to the __MDrivenDatabase.
Thanks